# Pixel tracking for email messages per user and per message

Tags: php

i want to track the email opens with pixle tracking,each user has an id in my database , i need know who exactly opened the message and which message and not just get a general open rate.

my question is do i need to have a pixle image with a different name per message and per user?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Bam.

Comment: @Bojangles after i've seen the answers i would say the shot answer is NO!

Comment: You don't need to have different images, but you do need to have different paths for same image. So... there's no such a short answer actually.

Comment: You can, but users can decide to not show images from your email, so they won't get downloaded and you won't get notified

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós right, nothing you can do about it,even google analytics itsel can't be accurate ;)

Comment: As I've read, there are some emails providers that block all 1px images.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos well my email will always contain at least one image, so do you think its better to use the bigger images for tracking, i know things will get more complicated but it might be worth it

Comment: It REALLY depends. A 5x5 px white image is really bad. Why don't you add a line at the end of all messages with the 'logo' and name of the email company after some line breaks? That should look more legit `brought to you by examplemail.com LOGO`

Comment: thats right, just use the logo as it will always be there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the same image for all emails but with different paths which making them all to resolve for the same one.

So, the image could be `example.com/bla/index.php?msg=1&img=white.jpg` and then do something like this:

```
<?php
// Here goes some more PHP ($DB initialization, etc)

if (!empty($_GET['img']) && !empty($_GET['msg']))
  $STH = $DB->prepare('INSERT INTO seen (`message`) VALUES (?)');
  $STH->execute(array($_GET['msg']));
header('Location: /images/white.jpg');
?>
```

I used recently some very similar for ajax, although using .htaccess and paths like `example.com/faces/89y3gf34gho.jpg` (which was converted internally to `example.com/faces/index.php?face=89y3gf34gho.jpg`)

Note that many users will consider a small tracking white image offensive, so, unleast you make a dedicate site like `imtrackingyou.com/track/index.php?msg=36&img=white.jpg` , hiding that that's not an image and what is doing could be desirable. For these purpose, `example.com/bla/5475.jpg` is better than `example.com/bla/index.php?msg=1&img=white.jpg`. This can be achieved with [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

```
 <img src="www.yourdomain.com/track.php?userid=xxx&msgid=yyy">
```

And then just use the $_GET parameters to track the user/msg, and redirect to a static image which will be the same for all messages and users.